# MYSQL trigger with if statements

Tags: mysql

I can't seem to make this trigger work.

```
 CREATE TRIGGER class_check BEFORE INSERT ON Category
 DECLARE x VARCHAR(1);
 SET x = (SELECT Type1 FROM Category);
 IF (x<>'A') THEN
 CALL `'ERROR'`;
 END IF;
 IF (NEW.MxLen > 3 AND x ='M') THEN
 CALL `'ERROR LENGTH MUST BE LESS THAN 3 FOR M CLASS LICENSE'`;
 ELSEIF (NEW.MxLen > 5 AND x ='G') THEN
 CALL `'ERROR LENGTH MUST BE LESS THAN 5 FOR G CLASS LICENSE'`;
 ELSEIF (NEW.MxLen > 30) THEN
 CALL `'ERROR LENGTH MUST BE LESS THAN 30 FOR A,B,C,D,E CLASS LICENSE'`;
 END IF;
```

The trigger above doesn't work the way i want it to and I can't seem to find the problem.
Basically, I want it to check if the type1 in the Category table is Not A then shoot an error. Everytime I try to add A, it will still shoot the error. 
Any help would be appreciated. I have the same for BEFORE UPDATE as well.

Comment: Which error message do you get? Probably `ERROR LENGTH MUST BE LESS THAN 30 FOR A,B,C,D,E CLASS LICENSE`?

Comment: I get the first error 'ERROR'

Answer (score 0):

The backticks are escaping the name of whatever is between them, saying that it is an identifier.  I doubt that you actually have any identifiers with these names.  Just use the single quotes for the strings:

Normally, `call` would have stored procedure name after it.  I am guessing that you really want `signal` to raise an error:

```
CREATE TRIGGER class_check BEFORE INSERT ON Category
 DECLARE x VARCHAR(1);
 SET x = (SELECT Type1 FROM Category);
 IF (x <> 'A') THEN
     SIGNAL '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'ERROR';
 END IF;
 IF (NEW.MxLen > 3 AND x ='M') THEN
     SIGNAL '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'ERROR LENGTH MUST BE LESS THAN 3 FOR M CLASS LICENSE';
 ELSEIF (NEW.MxLen > 5 AND x ='G') THEN
     SIGNAL '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'ERROR LENGTH MUST BE LESS THAN 5 FOR G CLASS LICENSE';
 ELSEIF (NEW.MxLen > 30) THEN
     SIGNAL '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'ERROR LENGTH MUST BE LESS THAN 30 FOR A,B,C,D,E CLASS LICENSE';
 END IF;
```

Also, it is not clear what this line does:

```
 SET x = (SELECT Type1 FROM Category);
```

It is likely to return an error if more than one row is in `Category`.